# Top high IO consuming process

Tags: sar

I would like to know the Top high IO consuming process. I used 'sar' for the same. But it does not display the pid of the processes. Please suggest an efficient way for the same.

From questions, previously asked I understand there is a utility called iotop. But unfortunately, I cant be installing it on our systems without organizational approval. Please suggest other alternative ways.

sar > file_sar
cat file_sar|sort -nr -k7,7|head

12:10:01 AM     all     15.06      0.00      6.59      0.53      0.10     77.72
01:50:02 AM     all     16.67      0.00      6.30      0.20      0.08     76.74
12:50:01 AM     all     11.09      0.00      2.64      0.18      0.08     86.01
12:30:02 AM     all     12.44      0.00      1.68      0.17      0.08     85.63
01:10:02 AM     all     13.43      0.00      1.83      0.16      0.11     84.47
01:30:02 AM     all     13.21      0.00      5.86      0.13      0.07     80.73
Average:        all     13.20      0.00      3.94      0.15      0.08     82.63
12:20:01 AM     all     10.94      0.00      1.53      0.07      0.08     87.38
12:40:02 AM     all      8.17      0.00      1.28      0.06      0.07     90.42
01:20:01 AM     all     15.35      0.00      6.14      0.06      0.09     78.36

Comment: Do you have `iotop`?

Comment: Just edited the question. I saw previous questions got to know about iotop. But unfortunately, we do not have it